# Grab data from a form and display in browser (PHP)

Tags: php, forms

I am trying to grab data a user selected from a drop down menu. User either selects view all, option 1, option 2, or option 3. I have a function called getUserCategory that stores the user choice in a variable called $category. I tried getting the value of the function by
doing:

`return $category` inside the getUserCategory function

and then writing:

```
$catChoice = getUserCategory();
```

I wasn't able to display $catChoice in the browser when I tried to do an echo statement.

```
echo $catChoice;
```

I also tried echoing inside the function

```
echo $cateogry;
```

but still, not able to display the value in the browser.

**Form**

```
    <form action="register_script.php" name="frm" method="post">
        <select name="category" id="category">
            <option value="viewall">View All</option>
            <option value="option1">option1</option>
            <option value="option2">option2</option>
            <option value="option3">Sandals</option>
       </select>

      <input type="submit" value="Go" />
```

**PHP**

```
 //call function getUserCategory ---------------------------------------------------        
        getUserCategory();
        //$catChoice = getUserCategory();

//function getUserCategory --------------------------------------------------------     
        function getUserCategory() {
            echo "<br/>" . "In the getUserCategory function Msg 1" . "<br/>";
            $category = $_POST["category"]; 
            //return $category;
            echo $cateogry . "<br/>";
            echo "In the getUserCategory function Msg 2";
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have a spelling mistake

```
echo $cateogry . "<br/>";
```

should be

```
echo $category . "<br/>";
```

Comment: I had to re-read your answer at least 3 times before I saw the difference between those two lines of code -- good catch!

Comment: There's a [campaign to clean up Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167342) by removing these typo-related questions, we could really use your help! Would you mind pitching in a little by casting a close vote on this question?

Answer (score 0):

instead of `echo $cateogry` use `die($cateogry)`